# Left Join with OR operator precedence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
dbo.Driver d
    LEFT JOIN #Test t ON  
       ((d.LicenseNumber = REPLACE(REPLACE(t.[LicNumber],'-',''),' ','')) 
        OR 
       (d.[BirthDate] = t.[BirthDate]
        AND  d.[LastName] = t.[LastName]
        AND d.[FirstName] = t.[FirstName])
        OR
       (SUBSTRING(d.[LicenseNumber], PATINDEX('%[^0]%', d.[LicenseNumber] + '.'), LEN(d.[LicenseNumber]))) = t.[LicNoZero])
```

What I am trying to figure out are a couple of things.

First what I had before was this pseudo code:

```
IF Driver.License = #Test.DriverLicenseNumber(No Space/Dash) THEN JOIN
ELSE
IF Driver.BirthDate = #Test.BirthDate
AND Driver.LastName = #test.LastName
AND Driver.FirstName = #Test.FirstName THEN JOIN
ELSE
IF Driver.LicenseNoZero = #Test.LicNoZero THEN JOIN
ELSE
DO NOTHING
```

I am trying to convert this psuedo code to the SQL up above. At first I had a scalar function that had the IF's in it but that turned out to be very slow.

Right now, the above left join is working, and is much faster, but I am wondering what the precedence of the statements are in the Left Join?

Also, If 1  OR statement is true, and another OR statement is true, and they are true on different records in the #Test table, what happens?

Is there any better alternatives to this as well?

EDIT:
The Tables are as follows:

```
Driver
LicenseNumber, Birthdate,LastName,FirstName

#Test
Licnumber,Birthdate,LastName,FirstName,LicNoZero,Address
```

Basically what I am trying to do is pull the Address from the #Test table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'precedence of statements'.  Also -- no offense, as I'll be happy to help later -- but you ask a question about OR statements that would be very easy for you to test-out on your own.  Give it a shot first, and if you still have a question, come-back and ask it.

Comment: easy enough to test. You can replace the individual join clauses with `true` and `false` equivalents and see which one takes' precedence.

Comment: Maybe if you post your tables structure and said what you want to select, somebody could tell you a better way to do it. I think it's a bad idead to join on such a complicated condition.

Comment: Table Structure has been posted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, `OR` does not short-circuit.  It **CAN** but it is not guaranteed to.

Basically the query optimizer looks at the conditions, and determines the fastest way to execute taking into account the statistics available.  If it looks like condition 2 will be quicker to test than condition 1 (say for instance the first condition will require a `table scan` but the second one can use an `index seek` then the optimizer is likely to check the second condition FIRST.

It may also run them concurrently if that looks quicker, then do a join behind the scenes and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Absolutely. And as for a condition being true on two records I think you may be confused as how this query works. (Or maybe I am confused as to your question) Only one of the conditions needs to be true to be a match. so, if record A matches the first condition and record B matches the second condition, both records will be returned.

Comment: @Rocky - I'm not confused.  If A matches 1, and B matches 2, and C matches 1 and 2, one of the C's will be eliminated before you get the result set back.  That's overhead you take on when you use an `OR` condition on a `JOIN` - it requires a behind-the-scenes SORT and dup-out

Comment: @Rocky - also I think in your example it's likely to check your second condition first.  Conditions 1 and 3 both look like they will require an index or table scan, condition 2 is SARGable

Comment: My bad. I was not meaning to say you were confused. I actually intended to state that the OP may not understand the OR clause or, very possibly, I misunderstood their question.

Comment: @Rocky - no biggie, I wasn't offended, just thought maybe I wasn't clear.  I agree OP seems to be uncertain about how some of these operators work.

Comment: Got it now. Ultimately it won't work for what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to point out that if you need to do this, your design is flawed and what you should be doing is fixing your design first. For instance if there are two records meeting different criteria with different addresses, how do you know which is the right one? You don't have a  field that tells you the date of the record which would make it easy and avoid all this nonsense. Next, any time you have to do a lot of functions in a join, your data model is flawed. Liscence number should be stored exactly the same way every time in any field in which it is stored. SInce you are getting it from a temp table, why don;t you fix the data when you put it into the temp table if you can't fix the data model.

The way OR works is that it will retreive any record that meets any one of the conditions. It doesn't care what order they are in or if there is already a differnt record for that person. If you want only one record for a person based on a precendence what you want is a UNION (and not UNION ALL) Statement.  Write the SQl to get the data for the first condition, then union it to the data for second condition etc. This will not be particularly fast but is how you would know that the record you selected was in correct precedence order.

Answer (score 0):

That SQL query will do as many joins as it can on the tables. A left join is "greedy" in a way there is no precedence in join statement conditionals like that.

Basically, if a driver meets more than one of those conditionals then you will end up with multiple rows for the same driver. You could try adding ***SELECT DISTINCT*** to that sql statement to limit duplicates driver rows, but I'm not sure that it will follow any kind of precedence of your conditional when eliminating duplicates. You'll have to look at the query strategy to know when the filtering is done.